# PHP script for checking if a user has entered his true full name

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

A user with a designated account logs into my page and they receive a page with a nondisclosure agreement. They must type their full name in a field provided at the bottom. I don't know how to see if the name is their name exactly. If it is their name they should be redirected to the inside of the site. If they enter anything other than their name they are logged out and their account is deleted (maybe just by changing their name in my database, which they use to login). here is some code that may be helpful in helping me.. thank you so much!

First and last name code:

```
<?php echo "$identity->first_name $identity->family_name"; ?>
```

Comment: My answer might not help you, but you might take a page from enterprise applications. They don't let users type in their names every time; it's harder to keep track of, and more prone to errors :change in capitalization, mistake with a letter, spaces, etc. No two users ever type their inputs the same way. But to answer your question, just explode the values, and compare them to the names you already have in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think that it is quite easy :)

You should do something like this in your controller action:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() {
   $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
   if ($post['first_name'] == $identity->first_name && $post['family_name'] == $identity->family_name) {
       /* Authentication ok */
   } else {
       /* Authentication failure */
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If the user gave you his/her full name earlier during registration, you can check the given name on NDA to see if it matches. If you don't have their real name already you can't check it. Another thing, true full name comes in at least two words. So while matching them, handle *spaces* and other punctuational characters carefully.

Answer (score 1):

If they already have an account with you, wouldn't it be easier if they log in with an email address and password, and you populate the fields with their first and last name straight from the database? 
What's the purpose of obtaining their information if you cannot use it when needed?

Comment: this is not an answer. This is a comment. And one that does not help me at all. I need them to type their name as a signature. If they fail to do so, their account is disable, essentially deleted.